# how to use CROSS JOIN to show precentage of total?

Tags: mysql

I have a dataset for Van orders and I need to calculate a percentage of clients spending who completed 1 order. I am using cross join to get the total. However, it keep shows error. any problem to it? Both part 1st can show the protion total and 2nd part can show all total. However, it can't be grouped with CROSS JOIN. Thanks!

```
SELECT 
    SUM(client_total_price) 
    FROM 
        (SELECT SUM(total_price) AS client_total_price,
        COUNT(idvanOrder) AS number_of_order
        FROM `vanorder` GROUP BY requestor_client_id
    WHERE number_of_order =1)
    CROSS JOIN (SELECT SUM(total_price) AS total FROM `vanorder`) t2
```

Comment: See [Why should I provide a Minimal Reproducible Example for a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query).

Answer (score 0):

I believe that you can use a common-table expression plus window function:

```sql
WITH prices AS (
SELECT
  SUM(total_price) OVER (PARTITION BY requestor_client_id) AS priceOrder
FROM vanorder
WHERE requestor_client_id IN (
  SELECT requestor_client_id
  FROM vanorder 
  GROUP BY requestor_client_id 
  HAVING COUNT(*) = 1)
), 
total AS (SELECT SUM(total_price) AS totalPrice FROM vanorder)
SELECT priceOrder, totalPrice, 100 * priceOrder / totalPrice AS percentage
FROM prices,total
```